# Android: Places SDK, unable to search all the places / search predictions are limited

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I have implemented Places SDK and used materialSearchBar library to get place predictions programmatically as show in the code below.

```
    Places.initialize(MapsActivity.this, getString(R.string.google_maps_api));
    placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
    final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

    materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            startSearch(text.toString(), true, null, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
            if (buttonCode == MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_NAVIGATION) {
                if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){

                }else{
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }else if (buttonCode == MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_BACK) {
                materialSearchBar.disableSearch();
            }

        }
    });

    materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                    new LatLng(24.856165, 66.669119),
                    new LatLng(25.125024, 67.899587));
            FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest predictionsRequest = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                    .setCountry("PK")
                    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                    .setLocationBias(bounds)
                    .setSessionToken(token)
                    .setQuery(s.toString())
                    .build();
            placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(predictionsRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse predictionsResponse = task.getResult();
                        if (predictionsResponse != null) {
                            predictionList = predictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions();
                            List<String> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < predictionList.size(); i++) {
                                AutocompletePrediction prediction = predictionList.get(i);
                                suggestionsList.add(prediction.getFullText(null).toString());
                            }
                            materialSearchBar.updateLastSuggestions(suggestionsList);
                            if (!materialSearchBar.isSuggestionsVisible()) {
                                materialSearchBar.showSuggestionsList();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("mytag", "prediction fetching task unsuccessful");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


    materialSearchBar.setSuggestionsClickListener(new SuggestionsAdapter.OnItemViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClickListener(int position, View v) {
            if (position >= predictionList.size()) {
                return;
            }
            AutocompletePrediction selectedPrediction = predictionList.get(position);
            String suggestion = materialSearchBar.getLastSuggestions().get(position).toString();
            materialSearchBar.setText(suggestion);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    materialSearchBar.clearSuggestions();
                }
            }, 1000);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null)
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(materialSearchBar.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            final String placeId = selectedPrediction.getPlaceId();
            List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS,Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS);

            FetchPlaceRequest fetchPlaceRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields).build();
           // FetchPlaceRequest fetchPlaceRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);
            placesClient.fetchPlace(fetchPlaceRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
                    Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
                    Log.i("mytag", "Place found: " + place.getName());
                    Log.i("mytag", "Place found: " + place.getAddress());



                    //FETCH SELECTED PLACE LAT LNG
                    latLngOfPlace = place.getLatLng();
                    Log.i("mytag", "LAT: " + latLngOfPlace.latitude);
                    Log.i("mytag", "LNG: " + latLngOfPlace.longitude);
                    //ANIMATE CAMERA TO SELECTED LOCATION
                    if (latLngOfPlace != null) {
                       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLngOfPlace, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                    }
                   else{
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                        apiException.printStackTrace();
                        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                        Log.i("mytag", "place not found: " + e.getMessage());
                        Log.i("mytag", "status code: " + statusCode);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void OnItemDeleteListener(int position, View v) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is I am unable to search all the places. It predicts only some places and not all; which could normally be searched using google maps.
**For example:** 
If i try to search MacDonald's in my city it shows only one while we have tens of  MacDonald's in my city.

Or any other restaurant or public place, it just wont search any of those. The search is very limited.

But if I implement Places SDK using  AutocompleteSupportFragment the search works just fine as shown below:

```
  //INITIALIZE PLACES API
    Places.initialize(MapsActivity.this, getString(R.string.google_maps_api));
    placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    // Specify the types of place data to return.
    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("tag", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("tag", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong while implementing it programmatically. Your help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two parameters of your programmatic request might be causing unexpected results:

1. `.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)` returns only addresses, such as if your user is going to type in a delivery address. If you want your search bar to be used for searching businesses like McDonald's, you would want to filter for type Establishment with `.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ESTABLISHMENT)`. If you are not sure what kind of query your user will use, do not set a type filter at all since this is an optional parameter.
2. `.setLocationBias(bounds)` the corners of the rectangular bounds you have chosen seem rather wide (longitudes are very far apart, about 77km) and short (latitudes are comparatively close together, about 27km). Double-check that these truly reflect the southwest and northeast bounds that you want to restrict the search to.

Here is the [documentation for programmatic Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically) for reference.